# Joomla's Jfbconnect Plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla's Jfbconnect Plugin. How and Where do I find CallBack Url or where it is generating in Joomla's Jfbconnect Plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see on this [link](http://www.sourcecoast.com/jfbconnect/docs/configuration-guide/enable-plugins)

Under the heading "Facebook Application", you can see the "Site URL" field on the screenshot.

perhaps that is the callback url.